# co_await'ed coroutines don't run concurrently in a console application

Tags: c++-winrt, c++-coroutine

I don't understand the output of my small code sample.

When I debug inside the MS C++/WinRT code, I see a call to WINRT_TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback() and WINRT_CreateThreadpoolTimer(). I think 3 execution of g() should happen concurrently.

This code:

```cpp
auto g() -> IAsyncAction {
    Log(L"Entering g()");
    co_await winrt::resume_after(1s);
    Log(L"Exiting g()");
}
auto f() -> IAsyncAction {
    Log(L"Entering f()");
    co_await winrt::resume_background();
    Log(L"First call to g()");
    co_await g();
    Log(L"Second call to g()");
    co_await g();
    Log(L"Third call to g()");
    co_await g();
    Log(L"Exiting f()");
}
auto main() -> int {
    init_apartment();
    f().get();
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs the following (with the thread ID prefixed):

```
24000   Entering f()
13160   First call to g()
13160   Entering g()
13160   Exiting g()
13160   Second call to g()
13160   Entering g()
13160   Exiting g()
13160   Third call to g()
13160   Entering g()
13160   Exiting g()
13160   Exiting f()
```

It does not run instance of g() concurrently. Shouldn't it?

I'm having a conversation about this on Slack (Cpplang#coroutines) where a lot of people are kindly trying to make me understand why my sample code works the way it does. Ast their explanations is not C++/WinRT specific, I hope to have another answer here.

Thank you.

Comment: C++/WinRT doesn't invent any magic. Those are just your regular C++ coroutines. If the C++ explanations didn't make sense, neither will any C++/WinRT-specific explanation. There is nothing C++/WinRT-specific here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think 3 execution of g() should happen concurrently.

C++/WinRT integrates C++ coroutines into the programming model to provide a natural way to cooperatively wait for a result. You can produce your own Windows Runtime asynchronous operation by writing a coroutine. A coroutine is a function like any other in that a caller is blocked until a function returns execution to it. You can use a co_await statement to cooperatively await the result of any function that returns one of these asynchronous operation types.

This means when you call the g () function, the co_await statement will wait for the operation in the g () method to complete before proceeding. So the behavior is correct. About more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency).

Comment: Thanks.
If that is the case, what is the purpose of those calls to WINRT_TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback() and WINRT_CreateThreadpoolTimer()? It sound like you're saying that applying co_await above is the same as calling IAsyncAction::get() on the return type of g().

Comment: When you call the winrt::resume_background method, it returns control to the caller, and then immediately resumes execution on a thread pool thread. In this case, you offload some work onto the thread pool. So the TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback function causes the thread pool to create a working object internally and submit its callback for execution immediately. The CreateThreadpoolTimer() creates a new timer object, a worker thread calls the timer object's callback after the specified timeout expires.

Comment: get() method will block the calling thread, it's not appropriate for a UI thread. co_await won't. But in your scenario, I don't think the get() method is much different from co_await.

Comment: @fft: The `co_await` operator returns control to the caller. Your caller (`main`) simply doesn't take advantage of this, by immediately issuing a blocking call to `get()`. If you changed your code to something like `auto result{ f() }; std::cout << "concurrent code\n"; result.get();` you'd be able to observe concurrent execution.